# How to delete content of a struct after it is saved in a bin file?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm writing a code to add a patient's information in a file. I use gcc compiler that come with Linux to compile my code. For example, if i wrote "Doe" for the middle name of the first patient in the file and if I add another patient in the file with no middle name, automatically the other patient's middle name is Doe. Is there a way to clear the struct so that the middle is set to null?

I expect midname="" but the actual output is midname="Doe"

```
void addpatient()
{
  system("clear");
  char ending; // end do while loop
  char temp;
  int check;
  char choice;
  FILE *infile, *checkid;
  if((infile= fopen("hospital.bin","ab"))== NULL)
  {
    printf("Error! opening file. File may not exist or is corrupted");
    exit(1);
  }
  checkid = fopen("hospital.bin","rb");
  do
  {
    while (fread(&input, sizeof(input), 1, checkid))
    {
      check = input.ID;
    }
    check++;
    input.ID = check;
    printf("Last ID used:%d\n", check);
    printf("Insert new patient\'s name\n");
    scanf("%s",input.name);
    printf("Does patient has a middle name? y/n\n");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    if((choice =='y') || (choice=='Y'))
    {
      printf("Insert new patient\'s middle name\n");
      scanf("%s",input.midname);
    }
    printf("Insert new patient\'s surname\n");
    scanf("%s",input.surname);
    printf("Insert new patient\'s address\n");
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    fgets(input.address,300,stdin);
    printf("Insert new patient\'s telephone number\n");
    scanf("%d",&input.telephone);
    printf("Insert new patient\'s mobile phone number\n");
    scanf("%d",&input.mobile);
    fwrite(&input,sizeof(input),1,infile);
    printf("Do you want to continue? y/n\n");
    scanf(" %c",&ending);
    system("clear");
  }while((ending=='Y') || (ending=='y'));
  fclose(infile);
  fclose(checkid);
}﻿
```

Comment: why do you keep reusing the same `input` all the time and why is it global? Just declare a *new* variable of the same type zero initialized with `{0}`, for example `struct patient new_patient = {0}` and use this instead of `input`.

Comment: also why would you expect since you did nothing to change it.

Comment: `memset(&input, 0, sizeof input);` before reading should do the job.

Comment: @alk it works. Thanks. Didn't know that memset works with string.

Comment: @Antti Haapala, I did ``` struck patient{ char name[50],midname[50],surname[50],address[300]; int telephone,mobile,ID}input```, instead of struct patient input;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, if i wrote "Doe" for the middle name of the first patient in the file and if I add another patient in the file with no middle name, automatically the other patient's middle name is Doe.

just replace

> ```
>  if((choice =='y') || (choice=='Y'))
>  {
>    printf("Insert new patient\'s middle name\n");
>    scanf("%s",input.midname);
>  }
> ```

by

```
if((choice =='y') || (choice=='Y'))
{
  printf("Insert new patient\'s middle name\n");
  scanf("%s",input.midname);
}
else
   input.midname[0] = 0;
```

> Is there a way to clear the struct so that the middle is set to null?

There is only one optional field but if you really want to do just fill all with 0 through `memset(&input, 0, sizeof(input));` for instance.

---

Note saving the data doing `fwrite(&input,sizeof(input),1,infile);` will not allow to read the file correctly in case the size of the fields or the byte order is not the same, or if later you add/remove/modify field(s), so this is not portable. Save the fields one by one using their external representation to be portable, starting by a format number to know how to read the file if you change the definitions later.

I also encourage you to check the value returned by *scanf* to know if you read a valid value.

Currently if the user enter a too long string you will write out of the field with an undefined behavior, limit the size of the inputs for strings.

---

(edit after your remark)

> Have you any links for the recommendation you said for scanf

If I well understand you have for instance `char name[50]`, even it is unlikely if the user inputs a word having at least 50 characters `scanf("%s", input.name)` writes at least 51 characters going out of the field. For instance do `scanf("%49s", input.name)` to not take the risk to have an undefined behavior (49 rather than 50 to have the place for the null character ending the string)

Note you cannot enter a complex name containing spaces using *scanf*.

> and for saving the fields one by one

do you use *write* but *fprintf*, of course doing that you cannot read already existing values by  *fread* and you need to use for instance *fscanf*

Also you (try) to redo

> while (fread(&input, sizeof(input), 1, checkid))
>      {
>        check = input.ID;
>      }

also each time you add a new element, you do not need that except before to enter in the loop to add the new entries

Comment: In the struct patient. I hand limit the name,midname and surname to 50. And address to 300.(char address[300] is this what you mean by limiting inputs for string?). I'm a noob in C. I'm learning by myself. Have you any links for the recommendation you said for scanf and for saving the fields one by one?